# Javascript function not recognized in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a java script function on my mouse over function for an image, however; the debugger says "function isn't defined." I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  The java script and tags look to be correct and it seems like I'm using the correct syntax to call the function.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Chapter11-1</title>
        <script type="text/javascipt">
       
        function overButton(img) {
         buttonImg="chapter11-1"+img+"_over.gif"
         document.getElementById(img).src=buttonImg
         }
        
         function downButton(img) {
         buttonImg="chapter11-1"+img+"_down.gif"
         document.getElementById(img).src=buttonImg
         }
        
         function upButton(img) {
         buttonImg="chapter11-1"+img+"_up.gif"
         document.getElementById(img).src=buttonImg
         }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="banner_logo"><img src="chapter11-1banner.jpg" width="745" height="150" alt="banner" id="banner" /></div>
        <table class="centerItems">
         <tr>
         <td>
         <a href="#">
         <img src="chapter11-1home_up.gif" id="home" alt="home" onMouseOver="overButton('home')" onMouseDown="downButton('home')" onMouseOut="upButton('home')" onMouseUp="upButton('home')" /></a>
         </td>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: It's a typo.It should be commented out.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, that's the main issue, you have opening TR without closing it, unclosed table etc.

Comment: One moment and I'll add the entire markup.

Comment: This way of implementing animated buttons is very obsolete. This is basically what you did 15 years ago; you shouldn't use whatever you're using to learn HTML. Look into CSS and :hover, and jQuery. To get "nice" buttons, you don't have to resort to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you spelled "javascript" wrong.
Change this

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

or just

```
<script>
```

Otherwise it's assumed that the script tag is something other than javascript

And use lowercase for the events, preferably you'd use `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Chapter11-1</title>

        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="banner_logo"><img src="chapter11-1banner.jpg" width="745" height="150" alt="banner" id="banner" /></div>
        <table class="centerItems">
         <tr>
         <td>
         <a href="#">
         <img src="chapter11-1home_up.gif" id="home" alt="home" onMouseOver="overButton('home')" onMouseDown="downButton('home')" onMouseOut="upButton('home')" onMouseUp="upButton('home')" /></a>
         </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
        </body>
  <script>
   function overButton(img) {
         buttonImg="chapter11-1"+img+"_over.gif";
         document.getElementById(img).src=buttonImg;
         }
        
         function downButton(img) {
         buttonImg="chapter11-1"+img+"_down.gif";
         document.getElementById(img).src=buttonImg;
         }
        
         function upButton(img) {
         buttonImg="chapter11-1"+img+"_up.gif";
         document.getElementById(img).src=buttonImg;
         }
        </script>
        </html>
```